# Responder a uma pergunta de fraca qualidade

Tags: debate, respostas, voto-contra

Hoje encontrei uma [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579948/323500) que estava muito mal elaborada, com a pergunta no titulo e um exemplo do codigo no corpo, evidentemente com pontuaçao negativa.

Eu decidi ajudar o OP e editei a pergunta para ajudar a melhorar o conteudo e formato (esta pentende de momento) e [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/579949/323500) para dar uma ideia do que é necessario para obter os resultados pretendidos.

Desde entao ja tenho 2 votos negativos, sem qualquer comentario seja na pergunta ou na minha resposta.

**Eu gostava de perceber porque que a comunidade acha que a minha resposta "nao é util".**

*Nota: eu percebo que a comunidade nao goste da pergunta, por mostrar pouco exforço, mas esta errado responder a tal pergunta se eu percebi o intuito?*

Comment: eu percebo, obrigado pelo suporte aqui nos comentarios

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [convertida em um chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144658/discussion-between-bacco-and-barreto). Quem tiver interesse em acompanhar ou acrescentar algo pode utilizar o link fornecido.

Comment: Eu vi agora e o fato de insistir no uso de `double` para valor monetário já me deu vontade de negativar. Vendo um pouco melhor, só daria para responder algo ali se estivesse disposto a fazer de forma muito elaborada, praticamente recriando o exercício, que nem sabemos o que é de tão mal elaborada é a pergunta, e sem fazer isso a resposta fica mal elaborada e seria um motivo para negativo também. Além do fato já citado antes de ser um incentivo à pergunta ruim, e que sem um negativo seria perpetuado no site e não só não ajudaria outras pessoas, mas atrapalharia. Tem melhores formas de agregar.